# virtual router plus could not be started

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I installed virtual router first, but it was not able to start.
So I installed virtual router plus(VRP) software.

I do "sharing" enabled in my broadband connection adapter "Local area connection".

But when I select "Local area connection" in VRP and click on "Start Virtual router plus" button is clicked, it automatically disable the shared. I have attached snap here:

Initially it look like this when I keep shared internet

[image: r1]

AFter I click on start button it says disable sharing automatically:

[image: r2]

And display error message : "Virtual router network could not be started"

I tried all possible sulution available on web but no luck

Comment: Please tell us about all your network interfaces and what you want to do with them.
Do you have 2 LAN connections? I don't understand why you want to share your internet connection to a LAN _and_ create a hotspot with virtual router if you have only one..

Comment: And - a bit offtopic - if you want to host some serious network services with that computer, windows may not be the perfect os for it. of course tools like yours may work but do have a look on some linux distros.

Comment: I have only one lan connection, I want to create wifi from lan by sharing it

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly? creating a virtual hotspot to get internet accsess from other devices?
why use third-party tools when you can do it from windows directly, most of the time those tools does use the windows command line to run those hotspots anyway...

from cmd run the following to create your hotspot:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=yournetworkname key=secret
```

now just run it:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

and to stop it:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

edit:
i just saw someone bumped this question, damm i didnt saw...
but anyway, if someone needs some help, then they could check out my answer...